# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException JSP

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp, jdbc, jstl

Есть home.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>

<sql:setDataSource var="dataSource"
               driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
               url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/web_notes"
               user="root"
               password="******"
               scope="session"/>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=US-ASCII">
<title>Home Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">

</head>
<body>
<sql:query var="notesList" dataSource="${dataSource}">
select * from notes;
</sql:query>

<div class="w3-bar w3-padding-large w3-xlarge w3-light-green w3-border">
    <label class="w3-validate">Таблица событий</label>
    <br>
    <c:import url="view/table.jsp" />

</div>
<br><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Пытаюсь получить список из mysql:

```
 <sql:query var="notesList" dataSource="${dataSource}">
select * from notes;
</sql:query>
```

Как только добавляю эти строки, кидает исключение:

```
HTTP Status 500 - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:  org.apache.jsp.home_jsp

type Exception report

message java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.home_jsp

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.home_jsp
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:176)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
servlet.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:40)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
      org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

root cause

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.home_jsp
    java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
  org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:131)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:62)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:171)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
servlet.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:40)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поменять вот это:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```

На это:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>
```